# How do I control aperture with lens reversal for macro?

Tags: macro, prime, reverse-mount

I bought a lens reversal ring to try macro photography on my 50mm f/1.8 prime lens. But when I tried it, I couldn't control the aperture as my lens doesn't have manual aperture control. I attached the lens normally and changed the aperture and again detached it to use it reversed. But still, the aperture hole was the smallest. How can I overcome this problem? And if not possible, what equipment should I buy to make this work?

Comment: [Will manual focus be available when reverse mounting a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26069/75526)

Comment: @xiota It's a Nikon D7000, and yes. I have tried it. Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @xiota thanks, the blog in the mentioned answer was awesome.

Comment: A possibly cheaper solution to buying aparture control gear might be to buy a lens with full manual controls. Many film era lenses sells for very cheap while still being good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Nikon F-mount lenses with mechanical aperture control, you can use the [Nikon BR-6 Auto Diaphragm Ring](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/37175-REG/Nikon_2658.html).

[image]

For Canon EF lenses, which have electronic only camera/lens communication, you can use an ["Automatic" Macro reverse mount adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1050997-REG/vello_rm_cef_macrofier_reverse_mount_adapter.html).

[image]

There are also other "DIY" ways to set the aperture to a desired setting.

For Nikon F-mount lenses they usually involve fixing the aperture control lever at a specific position. For Canon EF lenses, one can dismount the lens from a powered up body set to the desired aperture while holding down the 'Depth of Field Preview'.